# Add button in django admin site

Tags: django

[image]

how to put button like in the picture? and it will link in my html?

this is my admin.py

```
@admin.register(gradingPeriodsSetting)
class gradingPeriodsSettingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('School_Year', 'Education_Levels', 'Courses', 'NumberOfGradingPeriods', 'Status')
    ordering = ('pk',)
```

models.py

```
class gradingPeriodsSetting(models.Model):
    School_Year = models.ForeignKey(SchoolYear, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Education_Levels = models.ForeignKey(EducationLevel, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,
                                         null=True)
    Courses = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    NumberOfGradingPeriods = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by extending `admin/change_list.html` for that.

You can use [django-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion) as a [reference](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion/blob/master/reversion/templates/reversion/change_list.html).

Here's a screenshot of [django-dbtemplates](https://github.com/jazzband/django-dbtemplates) with django-reversion.[image]